# Need Help in Writing SQL Query Distribute Single Columns into Multiple Columns according to Detail Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

As pictures says it all I need. I have two tables named **"tblPerson"** which stores all types of person names (like Student, Parent, Teachers, Staff Members) and their is another table named **"tblStudents"** as given in **picture** which stores **Students** details in the form of **IDs** (IDs given in the **tblPerson**). So, i need output I mentioned in the picture.
So, Please help writing a query for this.
In Advance, Bundle of Prays and Thanks

[image]

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt. (And don't tag products not involved. Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple JOIN will do things:

```
SELECT  st.personName stdName,
        fa.personName fatherName
FROM tblStudent s
LEFT JOIN tblPerson st
    ON st.id = s.stdName
LEFT JOIN tblPerson fa
    ON fa.id = s.fatherName
```

Output:

```
stdName fatherName
Hamdan  Shahid
Sarah   William
Robert  William
```